# Downloading Tensorflow for Python - how do I get rid of this error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

I am going CRAZY trying to download tensorflow at the moment. I have tried many different things but I just either don't understand the instructions or it doesn't work for me.

At the moment I am trying this:

1. Download python 3.6 from https://www.anaconda.com/download/
2. Open Command Window as Administrator
3. Type:    conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.6
4. activate tensorflow
5. Type:    pip install --upgrade tensorflow

As per the tensorflow website I can execute this command:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
```

And it outputs `Hello, TensorFlow!`

BUT I cannot create a new file through IDLE and execute that code - only in the command window

Please help... of if you have a better solution for me I am all ears but very new to this so in need of simple instructions :)

Thanks!

Comment: you are on windows or linux?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is actually creating a virtual environment so you need to learn about that
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html
Basically it's just an installation directory so calling it tensorflow will not actually install tensorflow.

So please learn virtualenv with conda. Then do these steps:

1. create virtual environment with conda
2. activate virtual environment
3. install tensorflow with pip as below.

I recommend testing in command line right after and ensure your virtualenv is working. It is possible `tf` is not installing for some reason. I find its best to use binary install method as outlines here
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingAnaconda 
Basically you install it directly with the URL.

for e.g.

`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade \
 https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl`

p.s. someone is going edit crazy and screwing up my post so be careful.

Comment: Basically I did this following exactly the steps on the tensorflow website and it works in my command prompt after I have completed the above steps (I edited my question) but I want to be able to open a new python file in IDLE and import tensorflow but when I do it comes up with that error again:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Comment: i updated my post. sorry I missed that you had already tried some of these steps.